# Generate a valid private/public key pair

Tags: openssl, rsa, amazon-cloudfront, encryption-asymmetric, key-pair

I generated rsa key pair using below commands (tested on both Mac and Linux)

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```

I sent private key to CloudFront to get a signed cookie but I got below error from CloudFront:

```
node:internal/crypto/sig:131
  const ret = this[kHandle].sign(data, format, type, passphrase, rsaPadding,
                            ^

Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at Sign.sign (node:internal/crypto/sig:131:29)
```

I validated the private key on https://www.sslchecker.com/certdecoder and got `Not a proper format or SSL file is corrupted`. I verified a key generated on https://cryptotools.net/rsagen but that is also not accepted.

How to generate a private key correctly?

Comment: Perhaps use `ssh-keygen -t rsa`?

Answer (score 0):

Check here chapter 2, page 3-5. Maybe this error is down to missing line:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468

Comment: The private key I generated has these lines ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAyRvc4w4Pl+J6FTHbY+X4SIi52WMyLhxrRmFpJ6g/2FlwmVxk
.......................................
le2TXcqdpvDh7tD4icg7VT3AUdOp92YfecI8NBjjKQuR530sbGH9DpA=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: This might sound really silly, but your header BEGIN has only 4 lines to its sides. Try:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

5 hyphens respectively